# log4net configuration for a given class not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net, consoleappender

```
namespace Com.Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {

        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Bar));

        public void DoIt()
        {
            log.Info("Did it again!");
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sfile = @"C:\development\Framework\Logging\ConsoleApplication1\app.config";
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(sfile));
        log.Info("Entering application.");
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.DoIt();
        log.Info("Exiting application.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```

My log4net configuration looks as follows:

```
<!-- A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender -->
<appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">

  <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1 -->
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="A1" />
</root>


<!-- Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package Com.Foo -->
<logger name="Com.Foo">
  <level value="WARN" />
</logger>
```

The output of my application still shows log from Com.Foo

67   [10] INFO  ConsoleApplication1.Program (null) - Entering application.

**100  [10] INFO  ConsoleApplication1.Com.Foo.Bar (null) - Did it again!**

100  [10] INFO  ConsoleApplication1.Program (null) - Exiting application.

How do I configure such that Com.Foo.Bar stops from showing up for WARN level?

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you also post your log4net configuration?

Comment: posted. thanks for taking a look

Comment: In your config, if you change `<logger name="Com.Foo">` to `<logger name="Com.Foo.Bar">` does it work?

Comment: You have a default logger in `root` and the level is `DEBUG`. How do you want it to disappear? You should rather remove the appender from `root` and move it to `Com.Foo`.

Comment: Wictor: I don't understand. can you post sample code?

Comment: @WiktorZychla that doesn't matter. Com.Foo logger in hierarchy inherits appenders from root. But it has own Level, and nothing will be sent to appenders, if logging event level is not enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.. I was not setting the logger properly in Foo.Bar class.

Update the following line

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Bar));
```

to the following..

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("Com.Foo");
```

and it worked.

Comment: This is not the case. If you provided correct namespace for Bar class, then its full name Com.Foo.Bar. And it will inherit from Com.Foo logger in config file.

Comment: What is namespace of Bar class?

Answer (score 1):

Configuration, which you provided should work.

When you create logger `Com.Foo.Bar` it inherits settings from `Com.Foo` logger in hierarchy. `Com.Foo` logger inherits his appenders from root logger, but it has own level, which is set to `WARN`. So, when you trying to write logging event via `Com.Foo.Bar` logger, effective level will be retrieved from hierarchy - it's a level of nearest logger up in the hierarchy tree (root logger always has level). In your case it is `WARN`, so logging event will not be passed to appenders.

I think your configuration differs from what you provided. Maybe you are reading wrong configuration file. Try this code (app configuration file will be used):

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Or (even better) use configuration via attribute:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

UPDATE

If changing logger retrieving from `typeof(Bar)` to `"Com.Foo"` worked, then you provided us wrong namespace of Bar class. Because log4net behind the scene takes full name of type as name of logger. Thus with `namespace Com.Foo` all should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<levelToMatch value="WARN" />
```